# Check file name in python and move the file

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a file sorter Python script. I have used the watchdog library to observe my Downloads folder, how do I check a new file's filetype against a file-type dictionary and then move the file to the corresponding folder for each file type which I have created.

```
import sys
import time
import os
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

source_dir = "/Users/pradyneshnarke/Downloads"

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):   # create handler class which monitors the directory
    def on_any_event(self, event):
       if event.is_directory:               
           return
       event_type = event.event_type
       file_path = event.src_path


if __name__ == "__main__":

    event_handler = Handler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path= source_dir, recursive=True)

    try:
        observer.start()
        print(f'Monitoring directory : {source_dir}')          
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
        print("Monitoring stopped")

try:
    pass

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File was not found")
```

I tried using the split method to split the file name but I faced a problem that the file extension  is not always the same as the file type